# Looking for an old horror show that featured two stories after an introduction by a man in a manor

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

I'm looking for an old paranormal/horror TV show that featured two unrelated paranormal stories after an introduction by a man in a manor (he was standing in a darkened room, maybe candle lit and there were lightning that occasionally flashed) that I used to watch when I was a kid (aired during the 90s but could have been an 80s show).

Does this ring any bells?

Comment: Well, it's from the wrong decade to be yours (although possibly, via re-runs or a channel showing 'classics'), but it makes me think of '[Night Gallery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Gallery)'; did the man stand in front of a painting related to each story while he introduced them? Does [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/66475677/night%20gallery.jpg) look familiar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the 1981-1982 ABC anthology series *Darkroom*, which you could easily have seen during the 90s when it was re-run on The Sci-Fi Channel.  The host was James Coburn, and [as Wikipedia describes the opening sequence:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkroom_(TV_series))

> The title sequence featured a dolly-in through the corridors of a house to a safe-lighted darkroom in a crawlspace under the stairs. James Coburn's voice could be heard over this dolly-in, narrating it as follows:
>
> > "You're in a house. Maybe your own...maybe one you've never seen before. You feel it. Something evil. You run, but there's no escape...nowhere to turn. You feel something beckoning you...drawing you into the terror that awaits you in the Darkroom!"
>
> As Coburn's voiceover reached the point with "no escape...nowhere to turn," the camera turned toward various walls and closed doors.

From my own memory (I saw many of the episodes when they aired, and have seen pieces on YouTube subsequently) Coburn would also do short introductions to the individual segments, of which there were typically 2-3 per episode.

Here's a link to [the second episode on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d559tGuL4qw#t=02m30s) (I've tried to make it skip to where the program actually begins, at 2:30, but it may not work on all devices.)

Comment: The intro is nearly identical to "The Scary Door" on Futurama :-)

Answer (score 4):

It may be ["Thriller"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thriller_%28U.S._TV_series%29), hosted by none other than Boris Karloff. It ran in the early 1960's. The host (Karloff) did his introduction from different places, usually one that related to the stories. The stories on a given show would each have a similar theme - same type of crime, or ghosts or whatever.

[image]